# path generator video game algorithm

Tags: algorithm, game-engine, graph-algorithm, path-finding

I'm working on a game for iOs and I'm stuck on something.

The idea is simple: I have a player that must go forward in order to win points (and avoid the yellow bricks). 
Here is (on green) the ideal path in order to go forward inside the rectangle (from the bottom to up).

I'm adding a new row each time, so each new row has to let the player move forward (it can move to the left, right and forward, no diagonal).

The idea is to have some 'parasite' empty spots, so the user must think about his next move.`

So, my question: how to generate something like this (for any number of columns)[image]

Thanks.

C.C.

Comment: You should clarify whether your really just want it to be "not impossible".  For example, what if the 2nd line from the bottom is all zeros? There is a possible path through the rest of the rows (to the right), but if the player can only see 6 rows ahead, it's just luck whether or not they'll pick the right path.  Unless you use the same track layout every time (allowing players to memorize it), you should avoid introducing a luck element like that, since even an infinitely skilled player will eventually guess wrong.

Comment: Also FWIW it looks like the game in the video you linked allowed free movement along the car's current row, regardless of what obstacles were in the row ahead of it on the last update.  That avoids the problem altogether, so you could start there.

Comment: The player will see about 10 rows ahead. It should not be impossible, it should always have a "right" path to follow.

Comment: That doesn't clarify your goal - do you mean there should always be a "right" path to follow AND that path is always apparent to the player by the time the decision must be made?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I would tackle this backward:

Generate the "right" path then randomize the remaining cells with some heuristic that prevents it from generating a "wrong" path.

The heuristic could be something similar to this:

> Let line 1 be the closest row, and line 10 the furthest.
>
> Let a path be a series of contiguous 0s.
>
> If line 1 contains only the "right" path and all lines from 2 to 9 contains at least one "wrong" path, have line 10 contain only the "right" path.

This heuristic might not be perfect, it's just an idea off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

You can think about board like about [directed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_graph) [graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_%28mathematics%29). If you want check "Is possible to reach last row?", you can use well know algorithms as [DFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search) or [BFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search).

Ok. It works. But it's potential slow. Therefore you shouldn't use any of that algorithm after whole board is generated. Use it after any generated row! And if every node from new raw is unobtainable, then regenerate raw.

If you don't want algorithm like "generate and check", you add empty raw, check how many nodes are available and rand the number of that, how many will allow to go forward. Then randomly get a subset of them.

You can also write a simple random generator, witch return i from[0,n). If last area is on the left, you are going left, if right - right, if same - down. It's nice, because if you are close to end, you probably return to other side. So it will have nice shape. But for wide maps, it will lose benefits.

Better, but on same idea is smart use of distribution of numbers in random generators. (eg. look on Cpp random library, or other languages generators).

Code based on this idea (but very, very simple) in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11):

```cpp
constexpr size_t width = 8, height = 15;
std::vector<std::vector<bool>> board;
board.emplace_back(width, false);
board.front().front() = true;
size_t position = 0;
std::random_device gen;
while(board.size() < height) {
  std::poisson_distribution<> d(position+(position < width/2 ? 1 : -1));
  const size_t random = d(gen);
  if(random == position) {
    board.emplace_back(width, false);
    board.back()[position] = true;
    continue;
   }
  if(random < position && board.back()[position-1] == false)
   board.back()[--position] = true;
  else
   if(position + 1 < width)
    board.back()[++position] = true;
 }
```

Example of output:

```
- # # # # # # # 
- - - - - - - - 
# # # # # # # - 
# # # - - - - - 
# # # - # # # # 
# # # - - - # # 
# # # # # - - # 
# # # # # - - # 
# # # # # - - - 
# # # - - - - - 
# # # - - # # # 
# # # - - # # # 
# # # - - # # # 
# - - - - # # # 
# - # # # # # #
```

Answer (score 0):

You could maintain a list of decoy paths, each one with a position (X) and a count down (C) that starts at a random number less than the number of lines visible.

At each step you mark the cells for the good path and each of the decoy paths. You decrement each decoy path counter and remove any that are at zero. If the number of decoy paths is below a certain threshold you add a new decoy path with a random C and a position that's either adjacent to the good path or randomly elsewhere if you want non-connected decoy paths too.

At each step the good path and the decoy paths can each increment, decrement or maintain their X position. If two paths touch they merge. When they merge you keep the lowest C value to ensure that you can't have a branch on a branch that goes beyond the number of visible rows.

This approach doesn't require any advance planning or creation of a graph.